# Using PBS batch scripting, is there a way to view the contents of PBS_NODEFILE?

Tags: mpi, pbs

I read in the `qsub` man page that PBS_NODEFILE is created once mpirun, mpiexec, aprun, whatever, begins to execute.  Is there a way to view its contents?  I tried the following:

C code catfile.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char command[256];
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  sprintf(command, "%s %s\n", "cat", argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n", command);
  system(command);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

In my batch script, I run with

```
cc -o catfile catfile.c
aprun -n 1 ./catfile $PBS_NODEFILE
```

Output is

```
cat /var/spool/PBS/aux/1894.pbs01

cat: /var/spool/PBS/aux/1894.pbs01: No such file or directory
```

That's all I've got.  Is there another way?  Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood that part. Simply submit a parallel job, and `cat $PBS_NODEFILE` in your script.

Comment: The variable expansion of `$PBS_NODEFILE` happens in the shell session where you wrote `aprun -n 1 ./catfile $PBS_NODEFILE` and thus you already fix the argument of `catfile`. When `catfile` runs, it does so on a different host than the one where you typed the command and it tries to cat a non-existent file since `/var` is not shared among the different nodes.